# Como concatenar vários json como dict no pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas

Eu tenho dois arquivos json que eu gostaria de concatenar em um. Existe alguma abordagem para combinar esses dataframesjson?

```
json1 = {
  "105912": {
    "name": "Avatar - Tocasia, Dig Site Mentor",
    "cardset": "VAN",
    "rarity": "Rare",
    "foil": 0,
    "price": 0.05
  },
  "105911": {
    "name": "Avatar - Yotian Frontliner",
    "cardset": "VAN",
    "rarity": "Rare",
    "foil": 0,
    "price": 0.05
  }
}

json2 = {
  "105912": {
    "name": "Avatar - Tocasia, Dig Site Mentor",
    "cardset": "VAN",
    "rarity": "Rare",
    "foil": 0,
    "price": 0.0007
  },
  "105911": {
    "name": "Avatar - Yotian Frontliner",
    "cardset": "VAN",
    "rarity": "Rare",
    "foil": 0,
    "price": 0.0007
  }
}




import pandas as pd
from glob import glob


arquivos = sorted(glob('price-history\*.json'))


todos_dados = pd.concat((pd.read_json(cont, lines=True, orient='records') for cont in 
arquivos))


print(todos_dados)
```

o erro q esta retornando é ValueError: Expected object or value

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

arquivos = sorted(glob('*.json'))
```

Criando o dataframe que irá ser a base pro concat

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
```

Percorrendo cada arquivo, gerando um dataframe e concatenando com o df acima

```
for arquivo in arquivos:
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.read_json(arquivo, orient='index')])
```

Mostrando o resultado

```
df.reset_index(drop=False).rename({'index':'id'}, axis=1).head()
```

|  | id | name | cardset | rarity | foil | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 105912 | Avatar - Tocasia, Dig Site Mentor | VAN | Rare | 0 | 0.0500 |
| 1 | 105911 | Avatar - Yotian Frontliner | VAN | Rare | 0 | 0.0500 |
| 2 | 105912 | Avatar - Tocasia, Dig Site Mentor | VAN | Rare | 0 | 0.0007 |
| 3 | 105911 | Avatar - Yotian Frontliner | VAN | Rare | 0 | 0.0007 |

Leitura recomendada:

[read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html)

[concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#)

Comment: obrigado! ajudou muito!